# Имена языческих богов

Tags: этимология

Некоторые имена вполне понятны: Лада, Ярило, Даждьбог и т.д. А вот какова этимология имен Перун, Велес, Лель, Кострома (хотя тут я предполагаю, что от слова "костер")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ЛАДА**. Согласно мнению акад. О.Н.Трубачёва, праслав. *lada восходит к индоевропейскому корню* aldh- «выросший, зрелый», который дал в германском aldi- «человек». Таким образом, первичным значением славянского слова он считает «старший, муж, мужчина» (ср. упоминание лад — возлюбленных мужей — в «Слове о полку Игореве»). Перенесение этого слова на женщину — вторично. В качестве сравнительного материала Трубачёвым привлекается литовское имя Aldona, которое может восходить к предполагаемому термину родства *alda(s) = др.-рус. лада при помощи суффикса -ona.

Песенный рефрен дед-ладо/дид-ладо восстанавливается для общеславянского как *děd lada, то есть это название старшего родича (дед) и именное определение при нём. Возможно также сопоставление дид с балтийский корнем did- «большой, великий» (лит. didelis «большой», didus «величественный»).

---

**ЯРИЛО**. Неоднократные попытки объяснить происхождение имени Ярило производились ещё в XIX веке. Производя его от санскритского корня ar, греч. ερ — «действие возвышения, движения вверх», одни ученые находили соответствие между славянским Ярило и санскр. árvān — «конь» (в ведах: «быстрый, стремительный, бегущий» (эпитеты солнца)), сближая с греч. 'Έρως; другие предпочитали санскр. ŗnōmi — «воздымаюсь», греч. αϊρω «поднимаю»; третьи находили те же звуки в славянских словах «ярый», «яриться», «ярына», «ярица», «ярец», чеш. jar, словацк. jarice, польск. jarzyna и т. д., и видели в корне яр значение «стремительности, быстроты, силы, света, весеннего или восходящего солнца». Отсюда божество Ярило имело следующую характеристику: «распространяющий весенний или утренний солнечный свет, возбуждающий растительную силу в травах и деревьях и плотскую любовь в людях и животных, юношескую свежесть, силу и храбрость в человеке». Сохраняя за предложенными толкованиями относительное правдоподобие, можно установить только общность имени Ярило с словом ярый «белый».

По мнению М. Фасмера, имя «Ярило» происходит от рус.-цслав. слова яра «весна», родственного словам ярь «яровой хлеб», ярые пчёлы «первый рой в улье летом», яровой хлеб, яровик «животное или растение этого года», ярица, ярина «яровое». Слово восходит к праславянскому корню *jarъ, родственному авест. yārə «год», готск. jēr «год» и т. д.

По мнению Вяч. Вс. Иванова и В. Н. Топорова, имя «Ярило» производится от корня «яр-» (*jar), с которым соотносятся представления о яри как высшем проявлении производительных сил, обеспечивающем максимум плодородия, прибытка, урожая.

---

**ДАЖДЬБОГ**. Этимология теонима Даж(д)ьбог на первый взгляд вполне очевидна. По мнению М. Фасмера, это имя объясняется из древнерусского императива дажь «дай» и *bogъ «счастье, благосостояние» (ср. богатый, убогий), то есть Даж(д)ьбог — «дающий благосостояние».

Согласно В.Ягичу, теоним образовался из словосочетания дажь боже «дай, бог!». Л.Мошинский вообще считает, что Дажьбог — это просто славянское приветствие, принятое иностранными миссионерами за имя бога. В.Й.Мансикка считает первую часть теонима императивом, как и Фасмер, однако вторую, богъ, склонен трактовать в прямом смысле. Поэтому Даждьбог — это deus dator, «высшее существо, одаряющее людей земными благами». Возразив Мансикке, Е.Кагаров отметил, что первая часть этого имени не может содержать глагольной основы.

Л.С.Клейн также отмечает, что повелительное наклонение глагола не очень-то уместно в имени бога-дарителя. Он склонен согласиться с Б.А.Рыбаковым, что такое понимание имени («дающий») является поздним осмыслением по созвучию. Более верным Клейну кажется мнение некоторых исследователей: дажь- является закономерным русским смягчением древнего индоевропейского корня, проявившегося в словах санскр. dagh, готск. dags, нем. Tag «день», лит. dãgas «пожар» и др.[7] Фасмер, однако, считает такое толкование едва ли более убедительным.

Наконец, В.П.Калыгин и В.Блажек независимо друг от друга предположили связь между древнерусским Дажьбогом и древнеирландским Дагдой, так как эти божества весьма схожи между собой и по функциям, и по именам. Имя Дагда восходит к пракельт. *dago-dēvo «хороший бог» (в смысле совершенства, полноты). На славянской почве под иранским влиянием произошла замена исконно-индоевропейской части -dēvo на иранское baga (вероянто, подобное произошло и с теонимом Стрибог) и уже упомянутое смягчение на русской почве. Однако В.П.Калыгин считает теоним Дажьбог индоевропейским наследием, тогда как В.Блажек полагает, что имело место кельтское заимствование в славянский язык.

---

**ПЕРУН**. Славянская этимология имени Перун (праслав. *Perunъ) достаточно очевидна. Оно происходит от глагола* perti, *pьrǫ «ударять, бить» (ср. рус. переть, болг. пера, перем «бью, колочу») и суффикса деятеля -unъ (ср. бегун, прыгун и т. д.). Таким образом, имя Перун имеет значение «бьющий, ударяющий, разящий (громом и молнией)». В пользу этой этимологии говорит ещё и тот факт, что в славянских языках есть идентичные слова, обозначающие гром и молнию — рус. перун «молния», укр. перун, белор. пярун, польск. piorun «гром».

Многие исследователи сопоставляют имя Перуна с именами Громовержца (и прочих богов) у других индоевропейских народов — с лит. Perkūnas, латыш. Pērkons, др.-инд. Parjánya и др. Напрямую связывать имя Перуна с именами других индоевропейских громовержцев не вполне правомерно. Данные слова восходят к одному и тому же корню *per, однако имя Громовержца балтов и индоариев имеет ещё и суффикс -k-, которого нет в славянском* Perunъ. Поэтому лит. Perkūnas, латыш. Pērkons и др.-инд. Parjánya восходят к праиндоевропейскому названию дуба — *perkṷu-, ведь дуб является священным деревом Громовержца. В славянских языках это слово не сохранилось, поскольку ещё в древности было табуировано (что ещё раз подтверждает его сакральность). Само же название дуба -* perkṷu- означает избиваемый, ударяемый, т.е. подверженный ударам (молнии). Помимо дуба, имя Громовержца в индоевропейской перспективе сравнивают ещё и с названием возвышенности — готск. fairguni «гора», хетт. perunas «скала», др.-инд. párvata- «гора». Всё это позволяет реконструировать связь индоевропейского Громовержца с дубовой рощей на вершине горы, куда ударяет молния.

Некоторые исследователи радикально разделяют пра-и.е. *perō(ṷ)nos «гром, бог-громовержец» и пра-и.е.* perūn(V) «гора», протестуя против всякого их родства. Сближение между ними, как они считают, могло произойти лишь вторично, в результате народного переосмысления.

---

**ВЕЛЕС** (Волос). Этимология имени Велес точно не выяснена. М. Фасмер предполагал связь Велес с велий (великий) по той же модели, что белесый ← белый. Л.Нидерле, А.Л.Погодин, В.Й.Мансикка, М.Фасмер и Л.С.Клейн отделяют Велеса от Волоса.

---

**ЛЕЛЬ**. Большинство исследователей отрицают существование у славян наличие такого божества или персонажа. Во многих славянских народных песнях встречается рефрен «Ой, лель-ладо» либо «Лада, лель-люли», который и был ошибочно принят за имя божества. По мнению филолога Толстого Н. И., припев типа ой-лели-лель этимологически восходит к слову *аллилуйя*.

Лель — сочиненное польскими мифологами имя славянского языческого бога, будто бы поминаемого в свадебных песнях. Исходя из убеждения, что у древних славян были боги, соответствующие классическим, польские историографы XVI века — Меховита, Кромер, Стрыйковский — признавали у языческих поляков существование богини Лады и её двух сыновей, Леля и Полеля, соответствовавших Кастору и Поллуксу; Меховита ссылался, в подтверждение этого, на слова древних песен: «Lada, Lada, I leli, I leli, Poleli».

При более критическом отношении к источникам славянской мифологии оказалось, что существование бога Леля основано исключительно на припеве свадебных и других народных песен — и современные ученые вычеркнули Леля из числа славянских языческих богов. Припев, в разных формах — лелю, лелё, лели, люли — встречается в русских народных песнях; в сербских «кралицких» песнях (троицких) величальных, имеющих отношение к браку, он встречается в виде лельо, лелё, в болгарской великодной и лазарской — в форме леле. Таким образом припев восходит в глубокую древность. Старинный польский припев лелюм (если он действительно существовал в этой форме, с «м») А. А. Потебня объясняет через сложение лелю с «м» из дательного падежа «ми», как в малорусском «щом» (вместо «що ми»). В припеве «полелюм» (если он верно передан польскими историографами) «по» может быть предлогом; ср. белорусские припевы: люли и о люлюшки. Соображения об этимологическом значении припева лелю и проч. высказаны Вс. Ф. Миллером и А. А. Потебней.

---

**КОСТРОМА**. Имя Кострома (укр. Коструб) происходит от «костра́» (или «костри́ка»), которое в восточнославянских диалектах обозначает «солому для сжигания».